# Highcharts: How to edit styles of the exported PDF chart/graph file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, highcharts

How can i change the styles of the exported  PDF chart/graph file? like changing the labels font-family and font-size?
the exported file and the graph in my system has different formats.

see image:

This picture is from my system.

[image: Taken From my system]

This picture is the Online generated PDF. it has different fonts style. For me its ok if the labels are slanting, I just want to change its font styles
[image: Taken from Online Generated PDF]

Now this picture is from an Offline Generated PDF. Now this generated pdf has an awful alignment in its label name.
[image: Taken from Offline Generated PDF]

Does anyone know how to change font styles and fix the alignment for the offline generated pdf.

Comment: install same font in your PC, because PDF pic font from PC

Comment: @SinghKailash oh. i see thanks. but what about alignment of offline generated pdf?. do you know how to fix that?

Comment: try highcharts CSS Refer below Link                                                          http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo/

Comment: what CSS do you mean here?.

Comment: sorry JS,                alternative solutions is you can convert whole page as Image then Export as PDF.

Comment: @SinghKailash .. so i have found a JS fiddle here that converts the graph into image. he got the graph saved into a canvas i think Heres the Link [JSfiiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vincent1516/qkrwrx9w/) . if you know and willing to answer, do you know how modify this jsfiddle that instead of saving the image, it will open a new window and display the graph image with `<img scr='[dataurl-here]'>`

Comment: @SinghKailash coz if its possible the dataurl can be used to display image inside the `mPDF`

Comment: What do you mean by online/offline. Do you use Highcharts exporting module to export the chart to PDF?